# Divisors of zero in polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I have the following theorem:

> **McCoy:** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. If $f=\sum_{i=0}^na_iX^i$ is a zero divisor in $R[X]$, then there exists a nonzero $c$ in $R$ such that $cf=0$.

Ok. But if we consider the field $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and the polynomials $f=X^6-\hat{1}, g=X$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7[X]$, we see that $f$ is nonzero and non constant and $fg=X^7-X$, which is $\hat{0}$ by Fermat's Little Theorem (thus $f$ is a zero divisor). It is easy to see that there is no $c\in\mathbb{Z}_7, c\neq \hat{0}$ such that $cf=0$. What is wrong here?

Comment: No, in the polynomial ring $x^7-x\neq 0$. You are confusion the polynomial *function* with the polynomial.

Comment: To add some texture to Fredrik Meyer's answer and Thomas Andrews' comment: to *feel* why $x^7-x$ should not be considered to be the zero polynomial even though it evaluates to zero on every element of $\mathbb{F}_7$, consider that this same polynomial is also defined over every ring containing $\mathbb{F}_7$, on which it no longer necessarily defines the zero function. In fact, if $L$ is a *field* containing $\mathbb{F}_7$ properly, then $x^7-x$ will be nonzero on $L$ *except* on $\mathbb{F}_7$.

Answer (score 10):

What is wrong is this: there is a difference between **evaluating to zero** at all points (as does $X^7-X$), and **being** zero.

It is only over infinite fields that evaluating to zero at all points implies that the polynomial itself is zero. Your polynomial is not equal to zero, because $X$ and $X^7$ are different in $\mathbb Z_7[X]$. In fact, one of the definitions of $k[X]$ is the **free** algebra generated by the **symbol** $X$, meaning that $X$ satisfies **no relations whatsover** (except those required of it for $k[X]$ to still be a ring, like $X^a X^b = X^{a+b}$).

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, this is a confusion between the polynomial and the function defined by the polynomial.

In particular, if $i:R_1\to R_2$ is an inclusion of rings (or any homomorphism, really), under you definition, there is no homomorphism between $R_1[x]\to R_2[x]$. That's because a polynomial that evaluates to zero on all of $R_1$ does not necessarily evaluate to zero on all of $R_2$.

For example, given the inclusion $\mathbb F_7\to \mathbb F_{49}$, it is not true that in $\mathbb F_{49}$ that $x^7-x$ always evaluates to zero.

So that means that there would be no inclusion $\mathbb F_7[x]\to\mathbb F_{49}[x]$.

If you must think of polynomials over a ring $R$ as evaluation functions, think of them as corresponding to the collection of evaluation functions on *all* $S$ given $R\to S$.